# How to create multiple re-sizable sibling div elements that are constrained in by a container div

Tags: angularjs, resize

I'm using angularjs and attempting to create a div that contains four re-sizable containers.  I want these containers to resize in such a way that changing the size of a container alters the width of the adjacent container but no other containers in the same parent div.

For example, if I have four containers and I resize the left side of container 2, then I expect container 1 and container 2 to resize with container 3 and 4 to not change.  These four containers exist in a row in their parent div with the expectation being that resizing should only occur horizontally.  Width of the four divs should never exceed or be less than the total width of the parent container. Additionally, there should be a minimum width on all containers that restricts resizing adjacent elements below their minimum width value.

I have a partial implementation using [angular-resizable](https://github.com/Reklino/angular-resizable) but move containers are resizing when using this approach.  I believe this is due to the flex-box implementation for allowing growing and shrinking of elements to fill the space but have hit a wall as far as making this work as described above.

Pulled and modified code directly from angular-resizable api page to produce this example. https://codepen.io/CodeRequiem/pen/NXVVKB The resizing is exactly as I want it, but the restriction to min-width is not being respected and there are a few issues with elements being pushed outside the parent container on certain resizes.

```
<div class="row">
    <section id="one" resizable r-directions="['right']" r-flex="true">
        <p>Schedule part 1</p>
    </section>
    <section id="two" resizable r-directions="['right']" r-flex="true">
        <p>Schedule part 2</p>
    </section>
    <section id="three" resizable r-directions="['right']" r-flex="true">
        <p>Schedule part 3</p>
    </section>
    <section id="four">
        <p>Schedule part 4</p>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Details related to questions shouldn't be in comments, as they can be removed. Questions ideally are self-contained. Can you quote relevant parts of the code so contextually everything is one place?

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this was to switch from angular-resizable to colResizable which give an implementation using tables that will work for my purposes.  There is an example on their [documentation](http://www.bacubacu.com/colresizable/) page that describes exactly what I need.  The **multiple range slider** section shows a great example of this exact case.  Hope this can be used for a similar solution for others.